# Does dependency among keywords prevents implementation of search function using full text search features by DBMS?

Tags: c#, sql, full-text-search

Recently my supervisor assigned me to create a "custom search" feature in the web application similar to existing one. The data being searched comes from multiple table joined by keys or spatially.

[rough idea of joinings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvrEf.png)

While I think that [Full-Text Search features by DBMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/get-started-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017) would fit in this feature as it would more likely return relevant results (ordered by relevancy) and possible to adjust weight of keywords.

```
var sql = @"
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE_A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B ON ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
OUTER APPLY (...) 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(...) AS KEY_TBL ";
```

My supervisor turned down it and suggests that just follow the existing logic: craft the search query in back-end. it looks like this:

```
var sql = @"
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE_A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B ON ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
OUTER APPLY (...) ";
var where = @" WHERE TABLE_A.DELETED = FALSE ";
```

It looks complicated and it is hard to know the relevancy of each result. What I summarized the explanations from the my supervisor, Full-Text Search won't fit this case because...

1. Need to Create a full-text catalog & full-text index on tables which updates actively.
2. May unable to adapt complex searches, e.g. search different attribute based on value of keyword.

I still have 2-3 days to prepare for this, and would like to know If the above reasons were valid or not. Also, I do have experience on CONTAINS but not CONTAINSTABLE, would CONTAINSTABLE able to handle such complex searches?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Full Text Search is powerful for fast searching data that starts with a given string.
As far as I know, `CONTAINS` supports only prefix searches (suffix searches are not supported) meanwhile `LIKE` can achieve both.

If you want a fast query filtering on specific columns (even though they are in different tables) and you accept the fact that suffix searches are not mandatory I would definitely go with SQL Full Text Search.

In order to filter on columns from different tables you must create a separate `FULLTEXT INDEX` for every table.

For example, if you have three tables (T1, T2, T3) with they corresponding columns ([A, B, C] in T1, [D, E, F] in T2 and [G, H, I] in T3) you must first create the catalog:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG CatalogName AS DEFAULT;
```

After that, you must create the `FULLTEXT INDEXES`.

```
CREATE FULL TEXT INDEX ON T1
(A, B, C) KEY INDEX INDEX_NAME ON CatalogName

CREATE FULL TEXT INDEX ON T2
(D, E) KEY INDEX INDEX_NAME ON CatalogName

CREATE FULL TEXT INDEX ON T3
(G) KEY INDEX INDEX_NAME ON CatalogName
```

After that, you simple write your SQL Query (with joins or other logic) and add in your `WHERE` clause the following:

```
WHERE CONTAINS((A, B, C), '"keyword*"'
OR CONTAINS((D, E), '"keyword*"'
OR CONTAINS((G), '"keyword*"'
```

If your tables will suffer from Fragmentation, you can have a Worker Role task that is checking the tables and rebuild indexes if needed.